# Request header field kbn-version is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: jquery, ajax, elasticsearch, cors, kibana

I have set the Kibana config details in yml file as below,

```
server.cors: true
server.cors.origin: "*"
server.cors.credentials: true
server.cors.methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD"
server.cors.headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Engaged-Auth-Token"
```

But my jQuery Ajax call still getting the error "Request header field kbn-version is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response". Appreciate your help in resolving this issue.

Comment: You need to change the `server.cors.headers` value to this: `server.cors.headers: "kbn-version, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Engaged-Auth-Token"`

Answer (score 1):

Thank @slidehowbarker, and for me I config this in Elasticsearch.

*elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml*

```
http.cors.enabled : true
http.cors.allow-origin : "*"
http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: "kbn-version, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Engaged-Auth-Token"
```